# Media Queries issue in jQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile, media-queries

We are working on an application by using jQuery Mobile Framework. So far app working really fine, and now we are thinking about to use "media queries" conditional CSS scripts for different size of browser window.

Our idea is that, when someone access our app form mobile browser like iPhone/Android/Windows phone - they can view full width and full height. But when someone access from a regular desktop browser and it's width more than 800 PX , we need to re-size our app both width and height.

Issue is that, we want to set re-sized app window over an iPhone background & currently background position is fixed. I'd tried thousands of time for re-sizing width and height and able to re-sized width but can't re-sized height. Also, I need to change the position of our apps over the background.

Can any one suggest me how to change the height of JQM window?

Waiting for expert opinion.

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if it may have to do with the viewport setting. I think we need some more details. It's a bit confusing on what you are actually asking.

Answer (score 0):

I think the Viewpoint will handle the width and the content should handle the height of the page. I think there is a default for height as well.

> **Viewport meta tag** 
> Note above that there is a meta viewport tag in the head to specify how the browser should display the page zoom level
>   and dimensions. If this isn't set, many mobile browsers will use a
>   "virtual" page width around 900 pixels to make it work well with
>   existing desktop sites but the screens may look zoomed out and too
>   wide. By setting the viewport attributes to
>   `content="width=device-width`, `initial-scale=1"`, the width will be
>   set to the pixel width of the device screen.
>
> ```
> <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
> ```
>
> These settings do not disable the user's ability to zoom the pages,
>   which is nice from an accessibility perspective. There is a minor
>   issue in iOS that doesn't properly set the width when changing
>   orientations with these viewport settings, but this will hopefully be
>   fixed a a future release. You can set other viewport values to disable
>   zooming if required since this is part of your page content, not the
>   library.

- http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/pages/page-anatomy.html

Also there is a gradeA global config option but not sure if this will help:

- http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/globalconfig.html
- http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/about/platforms.html

> **gradeA** 
> function that returns a boolean, default: a function returning the value of `$.support.mediaquery` Any support conditions
>   that must be met in order to proceed.

jQM offers Media Helpers but it's been deprecated but you can still download it and use it yourself.

- http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/mediahelpers.html

They suggest using [response.js](https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond) developed by Scott Jehl (jQM Team member)